# Tailwind CSS help needed with NavBar menu for mobile devices

Tags: navbar

I need help with styling navbar menu for mobile devices. Currently I am able to either have all the buttons be on the left, but when i try to put them in the center of the screen they do align but its left-aligned in the center of the page whereas I want it to be center-aligned to the center.[this is on the left without any style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMfSg.png)

when i add this code [div className="flex justify-center items-center"] it becomes like this image.[which is like this in the center but still left-aligned text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp3ZM.png)

how can i make it center-aligned text so that it looks a center flow and not so strict.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make text center aligned use `text-center` in your div className. If this doesn't work, do this directly on the text, e.g: `h2 className='text-center'`.